# Setting up permission to view list of objects without add/edit permission

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to let a few users to be able to access the django admin site, but in some models allow permission to only being able to view the list of objects.

Is there an easy way of doing this or should I just create a view to show this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is support for "view only" object-level permissions, so you should probably just create a view to display this.

You could use one of the existing permission decorators to throw an error on save if the user isn't authenticated, but this allows them to view the object details, something you don't seem to want to do.